# Could not locate named parameter [orderByDesc], expecting one of [category]

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Could not locate named parameter [orderByDesc], expecting one of [category]
I'm experiencing an issue with an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate named parameter [orderByDesc], expecting one of [category].

I've executed a query, but it's not progressing and is giving me an error.

I believe the values are being input correctly, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Here is the @Query that I've written:

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Food f WHERE f.foodCategory2 = :category" +           
" ORDER BY" +           
" CASE WHEN :orderByDesc = '-protein' THEN f.protein END DESC," +           
" CASE WHEN :orderByDesc = '-fat' THEN f.fat END DESC," +           
" CASE WHEN :orderByDesc = '-carbo' THEN f.carbo END DESC," +           
" CASE WHEN :orderByDesc = '+protein' THEN f.protein END ASC," +           
" CASE WHEN :orderByDesc = '+fat' THEN f.fat END ASC," +           
" CASE WHEN :orderByDesc = '+carbo' THEN f.carbo END ASC")   
Page<Food> findInCategoryOther
(@Param("category") String category, @Param("orderByDesc") String orderByDesc, Pageable pageable);
```

I need to know where I should make changes and how?

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid query: if :orderByDesc doesn't match one of the options, it becomes "select f from food... order by DESC, DESC, DESC, ASC, ASC, ASC". IMO you are better off with a query per order option, or dynamically building the ordering onto the query with criteria api. The JPA specification states CASE isn't a valid expression for the order by clause - you could try to use it by including it in the Select clause and naming it, then using the name in the order by clause.